# Getting rid of feed items of other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have followed Hartl's tutorial to make a ToDoList with a tagging system, also with the help of this [word guide](https://medium.com/@sherzelsmith/add-a-filtering-multiple-tag-system-with-autocomplete-to-your-rails-model-in-rails-5-1bf88cd53e9) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBa2qs9CFZQ). 
Up till today, I am still curious how the code for the feed system implemented by Hartl in [Listing 13.3](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#sec-a_proto_feed) works. For my current application, the simpler version before the implementation of the tags manages to keep the feed observable on the home page of the owner of the microposts itself.

**Correct feed view that shows only own post**
[image: Wrong after implementing tags]
And the log whenever I try logging in for the first time.

```
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (36.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (24.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
```

However, implementing the tags now causes the feeds of all users to be shown.

**Wrongly displayed version**

[image: correct but pre-tagged]

Here is the log on my command line when I'm first entered the login page for the cased of the tagging system.

```
  Rendered collection of microposts/_micropost.html.erb [30 times] (80.7ms)
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts"
  Rendered shared/_feed.html.erb (86.8ms)
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (138.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (63.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
```

Here's my controller code:

MicropostsController

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy


  def index
    params[:tag] ? @microposts = Micropost.tagged_with(params[:tag]) : @microposts = Micropost.all
  end


  def show
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  end



  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "You have deleted a task!"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :tag_list, :tag, 
        {tag_ids: [] }, :tag_ids)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if (@user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]))
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome back, #{@user.name}!"
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user)
      redirect_back_or root_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

StaticPagesController

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if logged_in?
      @new_micropost = Micropost.new
      @micropost  = current_user.microposts
      @feed_items = Micropost.all.paginate(page: params[:page])

    end 
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy]


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end


  def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
     log_in @user
     flash[:info] = "Welcome to the to-do app, #{@user.name}"
     redirect_to @user
   else
     render 'new'
   end
  end

  def admin
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def destroy
    a = User.find(params[:id]).name
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "#{a} has been deleted!"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end

 def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile for @user.name has been updated"
    redirect_to(@user)
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Update Failed."
    render 'edit'
  end
end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                  :password_confirmation, :admin)
    end
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "You are not logged in. Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if !current_user?(@user)
        flash[:danger] = "You are not authorized to visit this page."
        redirect_to(root_url)
      end
    end
  end
```

microposts/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Filtered Micropost Page</h1>
<div class = "col-md-8 offset-2">
  <% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
    <p><%= truncate(micropost.content, length: 50) %></p>
    <p><small>Tags: <%= raw micropost.tags.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></small</p>
        <span class="timestamp">
            Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
            <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
              <%= link_to "Done", micropost_path(micropost), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Keep up the good work!" } %>
            <% end %>
        </span>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any clue how to solve the problem? Do inform me if more information is needed.

Comment: Please, show the controller code

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you shared, I think your problem is in the `StaticPagesController`, in the `home` action. There you retrieve the `@feed_items` as follows:

```
  @new_micropost = Micropost.new
  @micropost  = current_user.microposts
  @feed_items = Micropost.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

and I am guessing you are showing the `@feed_items` in the feed? If so, then by design you show all possible microposts of all possible users.

So I am guessing it should be something like

```
  @feed_items = current_user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

(not sure if you need/use the `@micropost` variable because this seems to be superfluous/overlapping) 
(also not sure how this is related to tags, because I see no reference to tags in the code you showed)

Comment: Just an additional question, do you mind including in your answer/comments how do you read the log and knowing what to debug?

Comment: You did not show the complete log, normally the log shows which action/controller is hit, with which parameters (if applicable), and then you can just follow what SQL statements are run and which views are rendered. It also helps to add your own log-messages to add extra info, using `Rails.logger.debug "some-message"`, but some people prefer using something like [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger). Hope this helps?

Comment: Isn't that only in the event the code doesn't run and shows the red screen on the localhost server. I copied my error message from the terminal directly because that's my only knowledge of how to use the log. The code still runs, just not the desired output, so only routes that are rendered were shown. I'm not even sure whether the error is supposed to be read top to bottom or bottom to top.

Comment: I am confused: there was no error right? Just not the required result? With log you mean the file `$RAILS_ROOT/log/development.log` right? It helps to see what rails has done to render a certain page. Error from top to bottom or ... Aarrgghhh confused, I have the impression you are referring something entirely different here?? Maybe you should open a different question for this?

Comment: Ah, I think we might be referring to different things, the "log" I sent you wasn't quoted directly from the `development.log` file, don't know how to optimise it. I only referred to the instantly generate information from a single clicking action, which means either the code runs or meets with a red screen on `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add user condition to the query in `MicropostsController#index`, e.g. by using `current_user.microposts` relation

```
def index
  @microposts = current_user.microposts
  @microposts = @microposts.tagged_with(params[:tag]) if params[:tag]
end
```

btw similar scope could be useful on show and update pages - otherwise users will be able to see and update content belonging to other users.

Comment: And the problem still exists if I only make the changes to the `index` action in MicropostsController

Comment: I meant the actions.